# MapView not showing Blue Dot Current Location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

In my iphone app I am using MKMapview to show locations,for the first time it showing current location with a blue dot.But if drag away in map and click the current location button it doesnt show the blue dot(but I am able to return the current location region)

```
-(IBAction)currntLctnClick:(id)sender{
  [map setCenterCoordinate:map.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you are using xib's then set the "shows user location" property to YES

Answer (score 4):

Considering you said that you can see the user location on first load, it's safe to assume you have `setShowsUserLocation:` set to YES.

Have you implemented `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation` in your view controller?

If so, be sure to avoid providing an annotation view for the built in user location marker.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //check annotation is not user location
    if([annotation isEqual:[mapView userLocation]])
    {
        //bail
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *annotationViewReuseIdentifer = @"map_view_annotation";

    //dequeue annotation view
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifer];

    if(!annotationView)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifer];
    }

    //set annotation view properties
    [annotationView setAnnotation:annotation];

    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you implemented the `viewForAnnotation` function? are you checking that you're not drawing (or failing to draw) a different sort of pin for the MKUserLocation?

Answer (score 2):

To show your current location with blue dot

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    yourMapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
}
```

Navigate to your current location on button click

```
-(IBAction)currntLctnClick:(id)sender
{
    MKCoordinateRegion location = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(yourMapView.userLocation.coordinate, 10000.0, 10000.0);

    [yourMapView setRegion:location animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT**
Or if still your blue dot is not visible then just remove your `MapView` from xib and drag and drop it again.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who came here by searching for GoogleMaps solution -
This is the property you need to set true.

**Swift 3.0**

```
self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [map setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just check that annotation is *MKUserLocation* while iterating in viewForAnnotation method and return nil if it is true.**

It works that way because MKUserLocation is also part of mapView.annotations array and you just need to pass it through without any modification.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation)  else { return nil }

// your viewForAnnotation code...                                              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if you are using Interface Builder, select the Map View and in the Attributes section, make sure `User Location` is checked:

[Map View Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMFPy.png)